# How to add items to each pagination number in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, bootstrap-vue

Pagination Reference https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination

```js
 currentPage: 1,
 perPage: 3,
 
  computed: {

paginatedItems() {
  return this.productsList.slice(
    this.currentPage * this.perPage,
    (this.currentPage + 1) * this.perPage
  );
}
    rows() {
      return this.productsList.length;
    },
  },
```

```html
          <div class="overflow-auto">
        <div v-for="(item, key) in paginatedItems" :key="key"></div>

            <div
              class="product-plp1"
              v-for="product in productsList"
              :key="product"
              id="product"
              :items="productsList"
              :per-page="perPage"
              :current-page="currentPage"
            >
              <div class="prod-plpimg1"></div>
              <div class="prod-plpimage1name">
                {{ product.key }}
              </div>
              
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <b-pagination
            v-model="currentPage"
            :total-rows="rows"
            :per-page="perPage"
            aria-controls="my-table"
          ></b-pagination>

          <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>
```

How to add pagination for the above code. I have list of products available in the v-for, And now i want to add the bootstrap-vue pagination. and display products in each pagination number. like 1.2.3,...

Added the bootstrapvue pagination, But dont have idea how to start with that, Can you please help me with this. Thanks.

Note:- For i am able to see all list of products in one place, So need to display items in each page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `<b-table>`, which knows to render `:items` as its rows, passing `:items` to a plain DOM element

```
<div :items="productsList"></div>
```

doesn't do anything. You end up with a `<div>` with `:items`, but it doesn't know what to do with them.

With plain DOM elements you have to iterate over the list yourself:

```
<div v-for="(item, key) in paginatedItems" :key="key">
   ...item specific stuff here...
</div>
```

In your case, it would probably look like:

```
<div v-for="product in paginatedItems" :key="product.key">
  ...product here...
</div>
```

Also, you have to define `paginatedItems` in `computed` as the current subsection of items, according to `currentPage` and `perPage`:

```
computed: {
  paginatedItems() {
    return this.productsList.slice(
      this.currentPage * this.perPage,
      (this.currentPage + 1) * this.perPage
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering .I have made the changes, But still i am unable to select items in the page wise.

In computed property i have made changes, But for this  v-for="product in productsList"

Do i need to replace with v-for="(item, key) in paginatedItems" :key="key" Or write one separate div.

Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I have edited my question code as said, Can you please look at that once.

Comment: You have to replace `v-for="product in productsList"` with `v-for="product in paginatedItems"`. That's what I meant, you shouldn't create a different, empty iteration. Remove that. Also, don't use objects as keys. Use primitive values (strings, numbers) (e.g: `:key="product.id"`). If you want my help in getting it working, create a [mcve] on codesandbox.io with what you have. What you posted so far can't be used to create a working example, as you're missing the component `<script>` and I can't know what's in it.

Comment: Also, the bits you posted from your component `<script>` are not valid syntax. A missing comma can easily break your app and I can't know if you're missing it in the actual implementation or only because you haven't copy/pasted properly. So please, create a *runnable* [mcve] on codesandbox.io (it's quite easy), place the contents of your component in `App.vue` and I'll have a look.

Comment: Now it's working with the updated answer by you. Thanks for your effort and thanks for your time. :)